# How do I find the angle between 2 points in pygame?

Tags: python, geometry, line, pygame

I am writing a game in Python with Pygame.
The co-ords  (of my display window) are
`( 0 , 0 )` at the top left and
`(640,480)` at the bottom right.

The angle is
`0°` when pointing up,
`90°` when pointing to the right.

I have a player sprite with a centre position and I want the turret on a gun to point towards the player. How do I do it?
Say,
`x1`,`y1` are the turret co-ords
`x2`,`y2` are the player co-ords
`a` is the angle's measure

Comment: As future advice, you'll get better help if you give a summary of what you've tried already, why it failed, and where you need help.

Comment: You need three points to define an angle.

Comment: I think we can assume a third point on the positive x axis, where the origin is (x1,y1).

Answer (score -4, accepted):

OK, using a combination of your answers and some other websites I have found the working code:

```
dx,dy = x2-x1,y2-y1

rads = math.atan2(dx/dy)
degs = math.degrees(rads)
```

The rest of my code isn't fussy about a negative value of degs; anyway, it works now and I'd like to say thanks for your help.

Comment: Post this code into the applet I linked to in a comment to my answer and you will see why this doesn't work. It puts 0 degrees as 270 degrees. So you'll need `rads -= math.pi/2`. Also, just because the code you have now accepts negative angles, code you write in the future may not.

Answer (score 28):

First, `math` has a handy `atan2(denominator, numerator)` function. Normally, you'd use `atan2(dy,dx)` but because Pygame flips the y-axis relative to Cartesian coordinates (as you know), you'll need to make `dy` negative and then avoid negative angles. ("dy" just means "the change in y".)

```
from math import atan2, degrees, pi
dx = x2 - x1
dy = y2 - y1
rads = atan2(-dy,dx)
rads %= 2*pi
degs = degrees(rads)
```

`degs` ought to be what you're looking for.

Comment: After searching the net for a bit, I found a good guide on trigonometry. Your answer is sort of right. Just remove `rads %= 2*pi` and use `rads = atan2(dy,dx)`; if you draw the triangle yo will see why.

Comment: As mentioned in the post, Pygame does not use conventional Cartesian coordinates. Going up is a _reduction_ in y. Hence the negative y and range correction (otherwise you'll get -90 degrees instead of 270).

Comment: Since code wins arguments, play with this applet: https://github.com/mgold/Python-snippets/blob/master/pygame_angles.py

Answer (score 2):

Considering a triangle

```
sin(angle)=opposed side / hypotenuse
```

Comment: This solution is bad, since opposed side might be equal to zero and python will crash.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want something like this - you may need to fiddle a bit - I may be off by 180 degrees.  You'll also need to special-case the situation where dy==0, which I didn't do for you.

```
import math
# Compute x/y distance
(dx, dy) = (x2-x1, y2-y1)
# Compute the angle
angle = math.atan(float(dx)/float(dy))
# The angle is in radians (-pi/2 to +pi/2).  If you want degrees, you need the following line
angle *= 180/math.pi
# Now you have an angle from -90 to +90.  But if the player is below the turret,
# you want to flip it
if dy < 0:
   angle += 180
```

Comment: Actually mgold's solution using atan2 is better - it avoids the `if dy < 0` part of my solution, because atan2 takes care of it automatically

Comment: Also, it's incorrect; the dy should be over the dx, not the other way round.

Comment: No, as the OP and mgold both mentioned, 0 degrees was specified to be in the y direction, so it's dx/dy

Comment: Ahh okay my bad.  That's what I get for not reading carefully.