# Turtle look at point (degrees calculation with two given coords)

Tags: python

I'm interested in creating a new function, which let's the python turtle look at an object. So I just need a formula, which calculates the angle that are needed to let the turtle do that. (0 = look to right) Example:

```
coords of turtle:  100,0
coords of point to look at: 0,0
result: 180
```

But how to calculate that?
Thank you for hopefully coming answers

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find the angle between 2 points in pygame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473930/how-do-i-find-the-angle-between-2-points-in-pygame)

Comment: It's tagged [tag:pygame] but the language says turtle.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some point class already (I'm not familiar with `Turtle` but I assume you do) like so

```
class pt():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

We can make two points

```
>>> ptA = pt(10, 10)
>>> ptB = pt(0, 0)
```

Then you can simply use inverse tangent with some geometry to find the angle between those points

```
def findAngle(pt1, pt2):
    import math
    dy = pt2.y - pt1.y
    dx = pt2.x - pt1.x
    if dx == 0:
        return 180.0
    else:
        return math.atan2(dy, dx) * 180.0 / math.pi
```

Testing

```
>>> findAngle(ptB, ptA)
45.0
>>> findAngle(ptA, ptB)
-135.0
```

Now as far as your question is concerned: The amount your turtle has to **turn** will depend on which way he was **originally facing**. The above method can find the orientation from the first point to the second, but you'll need to know the turtle's current orientation to know which way they need to turn to get there.