# How Can I Rotate My Sprite Towards The Player Even If Player Moves Position

Tags: python, pygame

so I have a sprite that shoots projectiles the projectiles shoot at the player I was wondering how I could make the sprite rotate to the player? [VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/f59bead67fc6a43d499238411285027a) the player bullets attack the player what ever position he is at but how could I make the ***cannon sprite do the same***?

my cannon class

```
    shotsright = pygame.image.load("canss.png")
    class enemyshoot:
        def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
            self.x = x
            self.y =y
            self.height = height
            self.width = width
            self.color = color
            self.shootsright = pygame.image.load("canss.png")
            self.shootsright = pygame.transform.scale(self.shootsright,(self.shootsright.get_width()-150,self.shootsright.get_height()-150))            
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
            self.health = 10
            self.hitbox = (self.x + -20, self.y + 30, 31, 57)
        def draw(self):
            self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
            window.blit(self.shootsright,self.rect)
            self.hits = (self.x + 20, self.y, 28,60)
            pygame.draw.rect(window, (255,0,0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 60, 50, 10)) # NEW
            pygame.draw.rect(window, (0,255,0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 60, 50 - (5 * (10 - self.health)), 10))
            self.hitbox = (self.x + 100, self.y + 200, 81, 87)


    black = (0,0,0)
    enemyshoots1 = enemyshoot(1100,10,100,100,black)        
    enemyshooting = [enemyshoots1]
```

my full code: [script](https://pastebin.com/1DACCXZA)

Comment: `atan2` is the classical "point towards something" function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find the angle between 2 points in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473930/how-do-i-find-the-angle-between-2-points-in-pygame)

Comment: see [pygame.math.Vector2.angle_to()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.angle_to) and [pygame.transform.rotate()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.rotate). And use it in every loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you can rotate the image to point to some co-ordinate quite simply.  You create a vector of the distance between your cannon and the player.  This is then converted to an angle with the `Vector.as_polar()` function.  The angle is used to rotate an *original* copy of the bitmap to the desired angle.  Image rotation can be fairly CPU-consuming.

```
class enemyshoot:
    def __init__(self, x, y, height, width, color):
        [...]
        # Make a Reference Copy of the bitmap for later rotation
        self.original = pygame.image.load("canss.png")
        self.image    = self.original
        self.rect     = self.image.get_rect()
        self.position = pygame.math.Vector2( ( x, y ) )

    def lookAt( self, coordinate ):
        # Rotate image to point in the new direction
        delta_vector  = coordinate - self.position
        radius, angle = delta_vector.as_polar()
        self.image    = pygame.transform.rotozoom( self.original, -angle, 1 )
        # Re-set the bounding rectangle and position since 
        # the dimensions and centroid will have (probably) changed.
        current_pos      = self.rect.center
        self.rect        = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = current_pos
```

So the idea is you take the original bitmap, and rotate from that each time.  If you keep rotating the same bitmap the slight differences will compound and the image will loose definition.

The other thing of note is that we're rotating around the bitmap's centre-point.  But the rotation changes the bitmap's dimensions, also changing the centre-point.  So this needs to be re-calculated and preserved.

You may find it useful to cache the rotated images once they have been rotated to save CPU.  Maybe round the angle to the nearest 10 degrees, and then see if it's already been rotated.  This would also allow you to pre-rotate all images and store them in a look-up table.

Edit: Calling `lookAt()` the mouse position:

[image: rotating cannon]

Comment: it seems like it just made my sprite bigger  [script](https://pastebin.com/SZxNmeBU) and it isnt rotating [Video](https://gyazo.com/89acda361d3c9b0b3afcef57af852db3)

Comment: @HabibIsmail - your `enemyshoot` class draws `self.shootsright`, `not self.image`.  So it's still referring to the original image.  You will need to adapt the example a bit more - either use self.shootsright for the rotation, or draw self.image, etc.

Comment: I removed that part and everything seems normal now but it just wont rotate towards the player

Comment: @HabibIsmail - Are you sure you're painting the correct bitmap?  Why not add some debug code that paints `self.image` at (0,0) every frame. Also verify you're passing the player's co-ordinates correctly, verify you're calling LookAt(), etc. etc.

Comment: how could I get the player position I dont understand that part because he will always  be moving  also wdym by bitmap? last I would need to get the player position then call the LookAt under it ?

Comment: At which co-ordinate do you draw the player bitmap?  That's the player position.

Comment: I draw the player at (40,460) and the sprite at (1100,10)

Comment: no not yet.. I still cant figure out  why it isnt rotating towards the player I think I am not calling the Lookat() and also I am still struggling on how I can get the player position at each frame and then call the Lookat()

Comment: I know how to make it rotate towards the mouse but not the player